# How can I render a vuejs component from a string

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue component that creates a table body with 4 td, the first td captures the id, followed by date, items and an options button respectively. I am able to display the data but the options button is displayed as a string instead of being displayed as an html element.

I have tried using v-html but it could solve my problem

sample data

```
{id: 4, date: "Jun 21, 2019", damage: 2}
```

component

```
<table-body :data="purchases" :cells="formatCells()"></table-body>
```

format function

```
formatCells(){
            return [
                { path: 'id', label: 'Id'},
                { path: 'date', label: 'Date'},
                { path: 'damage', label: 'Damage'},
                { key: 'option', content: purchase => '<table-row-options title="Options" :options="formatTableRowOptions(data)"/>'}
            ]
        }
```

table body component

```
<template>
<tbody>
<tr v-for="item in data">
    <td v-for="cell in cells">{{renderCell(item, cell) }}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script>
import _ from 'lodash'
export default {
    name: "table-body",
    props:['cells', 'data'],
    data(){
        return {
            options:''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        renderCell(item, cell) {
            if(cell.content) return cell.content(item)
            return _.get(item, cell.path)
        }
    }
}
```

I want the user to be able to see the table data with an options button. Any suggestions on how I could fix this ?

Comment: please share the content of that string

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, the way vuue works is with `template` tag, this is essentially JS injected into the HTML, so it is not string, you could use the `render` function to render it through JS then it would work.

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have updated the question with all the relevant data.

Comment: @Michael can you please share how I could go about rendering it with JS

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html
Also see here:
https://alligator.io/vuejs/introduction-render-functions/
and here:
https://snipcart.com/blog/vue-render-functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution will depend on how generic you need to make it. You could go all-in with a `render` function but chances are you can achieve what you want just by tweaking the content of the slot.

For example, you could move the rendering of the `table-row-options` into the template:

```html
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in data">
      <td v-for="cell in cells">
        <table-row-options
          v-if="cell.key === 'option'"
          ...
        />
        <template v-else>
          {{ renderCell(item, cell) }}
        </template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

If you want to make this a bit more generic you could do something using `v-bind`:

```html
<template>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in data">
      <td v-for="cell in cells">
        <component
          v-if="cell.content"
          v-bind="cell.content(item)"
        />
        <template v-else>
          {{ renderCell(item, cell) }}
        </template>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
```

In this case `cell.content` would need to return a suitable object instead of a string, like this:

```js
formatCells(){
  return [
    { path: 'id', label: 'Id'},
    { path: 'date', label: 'Date'},
    { path: 'damage', label: 'Damage'},
    { key: 'option', content: purchase => ({ is: 'table-row-options', title: 'Options', ... })
  ]
}
```